# IE7 overflow issue

Tags: css, overflow, internet-explorer-7

I have a ul with overlfow-y set to auto allowing me to have a nice scroll bar for all the li. However IE7 ignores all this and the list goes outside the container.

http://jsfiddle.net/asWeb/LnnmW/ see my code here.

I checked on the internet and the common solution was to put a position:relative to the outside div (registered_members) but it didn't work.

Thank you

Comment: Add position:relative to the ul tag.

Comment: hi there, it works but can you explain why pls?

Comment: A bug in IE7. Glad this helped. Will copy it to an answer.

Comment: By setting position:relative for an element you make it the containing block for any absolutely positioned child elements, whether they appear immediately below the relatively positioned element in the DOM hierarchy, or further down the hierarchy. So with relative positioning applied to the outside div, it _should_ work. But there is a bug in IE7 presumably with the rendering of unordered lists which prevents it from working. My solution forces IE7 to recognize that the the li elements are children of the ul element as far as rendering goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add position:relative to the ul tag. This will force IE to render the element tree correctly.